# Merging two tables using SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I need to merge.

Table 1 is :

| ID | Product code | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 100 |
| 1 | 102 | 200 |
| 1 | 103 | 300 |
| 2 | 201 | 400 |
| 3 | 301 | 500 |
| 3 | 302 | 600 |

Table 2 has

| ID | Product code | Spend | Product tenure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 100 | 20 |
| 1 | 102 | 200 | 30 |
| 3 | 302 | 600 | 40 |

I want to merge these such that only ID's present in table 2 are retained from table 1. Table 2 does not contain all the product codes for each ID, but I want my final table to have it.

Output must have

| ID | Product code | Spend | Product tenure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 100 | 20 |
| 1 | 102 | 200 | 30 |
| 1 | 103 | 300 |  |
| 3 | 301 | 500 |  |
| 3 | 302 | 600 | 40 |

Any help on this would be appreciated. I tried left join on ID, but it produces many duplicates.

Comment: *I have two tables that I need to merge.* Provide them as a combination of CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
    (
        SELECT `product_tenure` 
        FROM `second_table` 
        WHERE `second_table`.`id` = `first_table`.`id` 
        AND `first_table`.`product_code` = `second_table`.`product_code`
    ) product_tenure
FROM    `first_table`
WHERE   `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `second_table`)
```

Explaination:

Select `id` from `second table`, which wanted `to keep` from first table.

Because the `product_tenure` only in `second_table` select them with combined `id` and `product_code`

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Is there a way subqueries can be avoided because I work in hive and it does not support it.

Comment: Oh, Currently I have no experience in hive. Please try Akina's answer below. Its need specifiy Select column as said by him on PS. notes.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 AS t21 USING (ID, `Product code`)
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM t2 AS t22
               WHERE t1.ID = t22.ID )
```

PS. The query will return 2 `Spent` columns (they're present in each table, and nothing prevents their values to be not equal...) - so replace an asterisk with definite columns list.